# How to match the first occurrence of a character and split it

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file from which I want to store `Keys` and `Values` in a `String` array.

In this case, `Key` is something like "**Input File**" and the `Value` is "**'D:\myfile.wav'**". I'm splitting the text file lines by `**:**` character. However, I just want to restrict the split to only the first occurrence of `**:**`.

This is my code:

> Input File     : 'D:\myfile.wav'
>
> Duration       : 00:00:18.57

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"[^0-9\p{L}:_ ]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) 
{
    string[] dataArray = line.Split(':');
}
```

Comment: Can you change the format of the text file ? can you use "=" instead of ":" for pairing key and value? Do you have that option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using regular expression captures

```
private static Regex _regex = new Regex(@"^([\p{L}_ ]+):?(.+)$");

....

Match match = _regex.Match(line);
if (match.Success)
{
    string key = match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value;
    string value = match.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value;
}
```

The regexp is a static member to avoid compiling it for every usage. The `?` in the expression is to force lazy behavior (greedy is the default) and match the first `:`.

[Link to Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WiMA8b).

### Edit

I've updated the code and fiddle after your comment. I think this is what you mean:

Key: Any letter, underscore and whitespace combination (no digits)
Value: anything
Separator between key and value: :

Comment: The first line:  Input File : 'D:\myfile.wav'  fails (or any line thereafter) for the if statement.

Comment: @DebaleenSenguptaVehere `^0-9\p{L}:_ ` means no (digit or punctuation or letter or : or _ or whitespace). And your expression does not contain anchors which means that in the case of `Input File : 'D:\myfile.wav'` what matches is actually the inital single quote, not the whole string.

Comment: @DebaleenSenguptaVehere I've updated the code after your comment

Comment: I kind of simplified it out. The code doesn't look beautiful, but it works:

if (line.Contains(':'))
                                {
                                    dataArray = line.Split(new[] { ':' }, 2);
}
else if (line.Any(Char.IsDigit) && line.Any(Char.IsLetter))
                                {
                                    dataArray = line.Split(null);
}

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you do not want to split your entire string, but to skip all the content before encountering first ':' char plus one symbol (':' itself).

```
var data = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(':') + 1);
```

Or if you really want solution with Split:

```
var data = string.Join(":", line.Split(':').Skip(1));
```

Here, we first split the string into array, then skip one element (the one we are trying to get rid of), and finally construct a new string with ':' between elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it with regex (comments in code):

```
  string[] lines = {@"Input File : 'D:\myfile.wav'", @"Duration: 00:00:18.57"};
  Regex regex = new Regex("^[^:]+");
  Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

  for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
  {
    // match in the string will be everything before first :,
    // then we replace match with empty string and remove first
    // character which will be :, and that will be the value
    string key = regex.Match(lines[i]).Value.Trim();
    string value = regex.Replace(lines[i], "").Remove(0, 1).Trim();
    dict.Add(key, value);
  }
```

It uses pattern `^[^:]+`, which is negated class technique to match everything unless specified character.

Answer (score 0):

On this way you can read each line of the text file. You fill the json with Key = until the ":" Value= From the ":"

```
Dictionary<string, string> yourDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string pathF = "C:\\fich.txt";
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(pathF, Encoding.Default);
string step = "";
List<string> stream = new List<string>();
while ((step = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(step))
    {
        yourDictionary.Add(step.Substring(0, step.IndexOf(':')), step.Substring(step.IndexOf(':') + 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to read put information to `String Line`
after that, do this.

```
String Key = Line.Split( ':' )[0];
String Value = Text.Substring( Key.Length + 1, Text.Length - Property.Length - 1 );
```